# Google Foobar, string cleaning, failed the test 5

Tags: java, string

I am taking this Google challenge and currently on level 3. This question is called string cleaning.

Your spy, Beta Rabbit, has managed to infiltrate a lab of mad scientists who are turning rabbits into zombies. He sends a text transmission to you, but it is intercepted by a pirate, who 
jumbles the message by repeatedly inserting the same word into the text some number of times. At each step, he might have inserted the word anywhere, including at the beginning or end, or 
even into a copy of the word he inserted in a previous step. By offering the pirate a dubloon, you get him to tell you what that word was. A few bottles of rum later, he also tells you that 
the original text was the shortest possible string formed by repeated removals of that word, and that the text was actually the lexicographically earliest string from all the possible 
shortest candidates. Using this information, can you work out what message your spy originally sent?

For example, if the final chunk of text was "lolol," and the inserted word was "lol," the shortest possible strings are "ol" (remove "lol" from the 
beginning) and "lo" (remove "lol" from the end). The original text therefore must have been "lo," the lexicographically earliest string.

Write a function called answer(chunk, word) that returns the shortest, lexicographically earliest string that can be formed by removing occurrences of word from chunk. Keep in mind that the 
occurrences may be nested, and that removing one occurrence might result in another. For example, removing "ab" from "aabb" results in another "ab" that was not 
originally present. Also keep in mind that your spy's original message might have been an empty string.

chunk and word will only consist of lowercase letters [a-z].
chunk will have no more than 20 characters.
word will have at least one character, and no more than the number of characters in chunk.

## Test cases

Inputs:
    (string) chunk = "lololololo"
    (string) word = "lol"
Output:
    (string) "looo"

Inputs:
    (string) chunk = "goodgooogoogfogoood"
    (string) word = "goo"
Output:
    (string) "dogfood"

Here is my code:

```
public class Answer {   
public static String answer(String chunk, String word)
{
    if (compareString(chunk, word)) return "";
    String s1 = checkBack(chunk, word);
    String s2 = checkFront(chunk, word);
    if (s2.length() < s1.length()) return s2;
    else return s1;
}

private static String checkBack(String chunk, String word)
{
    if (compareString(chunk, word)) return "";
    if (chunk.length() <= word.length()) return chunk;
    for (int i = chunk.length(); i >= word.length(); i--)
    {
        if (compareString(chunk.substring(i-word.length(), i), word))
        {
            return checkBack(removeAt(i-word.length(), i-1, chunk), word);
        }
    }
    return chunk;
}

private static String checkFront(String chunk, String word)
{
    if (compareString(chunk, word)) return "";
    if (chunk.length() <= word.length()) return chunk;
    for (int i = 0; i < chunk.length()-word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (compareString(chunk.substring(i, word.length()+i), word))
        {
            return checkFront(removeAt(i, word.length()+i-1, chunk), word);
        }
    }
    return chunk;
}

private static String removeAt(int startIndex, int endIndex, String input)
{
   if (endIndex+1 == input.length())
   {
       return input.substring(0, startIndex);
   }
   else 
   {
      return input.substring(0, startIndex) + input.substring(endIndex+1);
   }
 }

 private static boolean compareString(String s1, String s2)
 {
   char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
   char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();
   if (c1.length != c2.length) return false;
   for (int i = 0; i < c1.length; i++)
   {
       if (c1[i] != c2[i]) return false;      
   }
   return true;
 }
```

My code passed the first four tests and failed the test 5. I have done fair amount of testings but have not found any possible reason that it failed the test. Please take a look and see if you can find more ways of testing it or any possible reason that it failed the test 5. Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE**
I've modified my code according to the test case proposed by Ken. I passes his test case but still failed Test 5.

Comment: What is test 5? Or are you not told that? Oh, and there is [`String.compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) that you should use instead of your own.

Comment: Here's a failing test case, I think, from code inspection: `answer("llolol", "lol");` Your code works backwards, so you get `"llo"` as the answer, but the answer should be `"lLOLol"` -> `"lol"` -> `""`.

Comment: Thank you Ken! You are correct, I don't know what the test 5 is. Great catch on the test cast! Thank you and I will update my code to take care of this and run it again!

Comment: I've updated my code according to the test case. It passes the new test case but still fails Test 5.

Answer (score 1):

1. In function `CheckFront`, you are only doing recursion on `CheckFront`, instead of both `CheckFront` and `CheckBack`
2. Same in `CheckBack`
3. There are too many recursions and thus too many function calls, which would be real slow in Google Foobar. I think iteration is a lot better(which is what I used).
4. What if two String are same length but s2 is 'lo' and s1 is 'ol'. I think you are mixing up lexi order with length

   ```
   (s2.length() < s1.length()) return s2;
   else return s1;
   ```
5. What if you have a special case, which you have to remove the middle word first to get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much more to add than what lance has said, however,I have the same problem that I get stuck at test 5. Here is the python code that I used:

```
def string_cleaner(chunk, word):
     rev_chunk = chunk[::-1]
     rev_word = word[::-1]
     while word in chunk or rev_word in rev_chunk:
        chunk = chunk.replace(word,'')
        rev_chunk = rev_chunk.replace(rev_word,'')
     rev_chunk = rev_chunk[::-1]
     if len(rev_chunk) != len(chunk):
        solved_words = min([chunk, rev_chunk], key = len)
     else:
        solved_words_list = sorted([chunk, rev_chunk])
        solved_words = solved_words_list[0]
     return solved_words
```

The code successfully ran Ken Y-N test case as well. Lance brings up an interesting point, is it necessary to the check the chunk forwards and backwards each time the chunk is reduced or will you ultimately come to the same answer either way?

For example: if the chunk is 'llolollol' and the word is 'lol'.

[image]

By checking forwards and backwards at each iteration, you get to the same answer as you would if you only checked forwards and only checked backwards: a blank string ('') and the 3 letter chunk ('llo')